# Back up localdb for db migration

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I've made my app on LocalDb\v11.0 on my own PC, and I'm trying to launch the website now. First I need to get the database filled with test data.

I think the best way to do this is make a .bak file of my current database and restore it on the host.

But how do I make a back up file (.BAK) of my LocalDb inside MVS?

Comment: can you not just copy the .mdb file? You might need the .ldf too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to back up my Database using a SQL query.

```
BACKUP DATABASE AdventureWorks2008R2
TO DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\AdventureWorks2008R2.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of AdventureWorks2008R2';
```

found this on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don' think that you can do this from VS but you can definitely do it from SSMSE 2012. You can download it from [Microsoft's Site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062). You can connect to (localdb)\v11.0 and you should be able to see your database. From here you can do a backup as well as connect to your production Db and do a restore from that backup.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is possible to work on this on VS. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web.

Follow the steps:

In VS, go to Tools->SQL Server->New Query
Type in the following:

```
USE "yourdatabasename";
GO
BACKUP DATABASE "yourdatabasename"
TO DISK = 'C:\yourlocalpath\yourdatabasename.Bak'
   WITH FORMAT,
      MEDIANAME = 'Z_SQLServerBackups',
      NAME = 'Full Backup of yourdatabasename';
GO
```